# using dplyr to widen data, automatically order vars and sum widened columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, pipe, tidyr

I'm trying to perform some functions I've already completed/gotten help with but I'd like to add some more columns using the results I have. I want to do a total of each year at the end of each year's set with a grand total at the end. And there are two columns that get dropped that I'd like to retain as totals.
please let me know if anymore info is needed. And thanks in advance.

```
    np<-structure(list(STATE_ABBR = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L,2L, 1L, 3L, 3L,2L, 2L),
                           .Label = c("CA", "KY", "NM"), class = "factor"),
                       
                   REPORTING_YEAR = structure(c(3L,1L, 3L,3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L),
                           .Label = c("1990", "2000", "2005"), class = "factor"),
                    
                      COUNTY_NAME = structure(c(2L,1L, 3L,3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 4L),
                           .Label = c("FRESNO", "ORANGE", "CARROLL","JEFFERSON", "TAYLOR"), class = "factor"), 
                    
                         CATEGORY = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L,2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L),
                           .Label = c("AIR","OnSite_LAND", "POTW METALS"), class = "factor"),
                    
           `SUM(REL_EST_AMT_SUM)` = c(14000,23149, 5617000,123, 23, 250, 1300, 0, 5),
                    
                       CARCINOGEN = structure(c(2L,1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
                        CLEAN_AIR = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("N","Y"), class = "factor")),
             row.names = c("62993", "49717","63290","00005", "19700", "332510", "323501", "67491", "62086"), class = "data.frame")
      
    NP<-arrange(np,STATE_ABBR,REPORTING_YEAR,COUNTY_NAME)


NP
           STATE_ABBR REPORTING_YEAR COUNTY_NAME    CATEGORY SUM(REL_EST_AMT_SUM) CARCINOGEN CLEAN_AIR
    49717          CA           1990      FRESNO OnSite_LAND                23149          N         N
    19700          CA           2000      ORANGE OnSite_LAND                   23          N         Y
    67491          KY           1990      TAYLOR POTW METALS                    0          N         N
    62086          KY           2000   JEFFERSON OnSite_LAND                    5          N         Y
    62993          KY           2005      ORANGE         AIR                14000          Y         Y
    63290          KY           2005     CARROLL         AIR              5617000          N         Y
    00005          KY           2005     CARROLL OnSite_LAND                  123          N         Y
    332510         NM           1990     CARROLL         AIR                  250          Y         Y
    323501         NM           2000      FRESNO POTW METALS                 1300          N         Y
    NP<-pivot_wider(NP, 
                    id_cols = c(STATE_ABBR, COUNTY_NAME), 
                    names_from = c(REPORTING_YEAR,CATEGORY), 
                    values_from = `SUM(REL_EST_AMT_SUM)`, 
                    values_fn = sum, 
                    values_fill = 0L)


NP
    # A tibble: 8 x 9
    STATE_ABBR  COUNTY_NAME  `1990_OnSite_LAN~`  `1990_POTW METAL~`  `1990_AIR`    "Total_1990"   2000_OnSite_LAN~`  `2000_POTW METAL~`  "total_2000"  `2005_AIR`  `2005_OnSite_LAN   "total_2005"   CARCINOGEN   CLEAN_AIR
      <fct>      <fct>                   <dbl>             <dbl>         <dbl>                             <dbl>                 <dbl>                     <dbl>              <dbl>                          0           0
     CA         FRESNO                  23149                 0             0            23149                0                     0             0           0                  0               0           0           1
     CA         ORANGE                      0                 0             0                0               23                     0            23           0                  0               0           0           0
     KY         TAYLOR                      0                 0             0                0                0                     0             0           0                  0               0           0           1
     KY         JEFFERSON                   0                 0             0                0                5                     0             5           0                  0               0           1           1
     KY         ORANGE                      0                 0             0                0                0                     0             0       14000                  0           14000           0           1
     KY         CARROLL                     0                 0             0                0                0                     0             0     5617000                123         5617123           0           2
     NM         CARROLL                     0                 0           250              250                0                     0             0           0                  0               0           1           1
     NM         FRESNO                      0                 0             0                0                0                  1300          1300           0                  0               0           0           1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have two more columns, I think this approach works better (and perhaps eaiser to understand).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

make_yearly_total_cols <- 
  . %>% 
  group_by(STATE_ABBR, COUNTY_NAME, REPORTING_YEAR) %>% 
  summarise(
    CATEGORY = "total", 
    across(`SUM(REL_EST_AMT_SUM)`, sum), 
    .groups = "drop"
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = c(CATEGORY, REPORTING_YEAR), 
    values_from = `SUM(REL_EST_AMT_SUM)`, 
    values_fill = 0L
  )

make_grand_total_cols <- 
  . %>% 
  group_by(STATE_ABBR, COUNTY_NAME) %>% 
  summarise(
    CATEGORY = "grand_total", 
    across(`SUM(REL_EST_AMT_SUM)`, sum), 
    across(c(CARCINOGEN, CLEAN_AIR), ~sum(c("N" = 0L, "Y" = 1L)[.])), 
    .groups = "drop"
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = CATEGORY, 
    values_from = `SUM(REL_EST_AMT_SUM)`, 
    values_fill = 0L
  )

make_category_cols <- 
  . %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(STATE_ABBR, COUNTY_NAME), 
    names_from = c(CATEGORY, REPORTING_YEAR), 
    values_from = `SUM(REL_EST_AMT_SUM)`, 
    values_fn = sum, 
    values_fill = 0L
  )

make_category_cols(NP) %>% 
  left_join(make_yearly_total_cols(NP), by = c("STATE_ABBR", "COUNTY_NAME")) %>% 
  left_join(make_grand_total_cols(NP), by = c("STATE_ABBR", "COUNTY_NAME")) %>% 
  select(
    STATE_ABBR, COUNTY_NAME, 
    ends_with("1990"), ends_with("2000"), ends_with("2005"), 
    grand_total, CARCINOGEN, CLEAN_AIR
  )
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 15
  STATE_ABBR COUNTY_NAME OnSite_LAND_1990 `POTW METALS_1990` AIR_1990 total_1990 OnSite_LAND_2000 `POTW METALS_2000` total_2000 AIR_2005 OnSite_LAND_2005 total_2005 grand_total CARCINOGEN CLEAN_AIR
  <fct>      <fct>                  <dbl>              <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>            <dbl>              <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>            <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <int>     <int>
1 CA         FRESNO                 23149                  0        0      23149                0                  0          0        0                0          0       23149          0         0
2 CA         ORANGE                     0                  0        0          0               23                  0         23        0                0          0          23          0         1
3 KY         TAYLOR                     0                  0        0          0                0                  0          0        0                0          0           0          0         0
4 KY         JEFFERSON                  0                  0        0          0                5                  0          5        0                0          0           5          0         1
5 KY         ORANGE                     0                  0        0          0                0                  0          0    14000                0      14000       14000          1         1
6 KY         CARROLL                    0                  0        0          0                0                  0          0  5617000              123    5617123     5617123          0         2
7 NM         CARROLL                    0                  0      250        250                0                  0          0        0                0          0         250          1         1
8 NM         FRESNO                     0                  0        0          0                0               1300       1300        0                0          0        1300          0         1
```

---

If you would like to know more about the logic behind the old approach, see below.

#### Old

Here is a `tidyverse` solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

NP %>% 
  rows_insert(
    (.) %>% 
      group_by(STATE_ABBR, COUNTY_NAME, REPORTING_YEAR) %>% 
      summarise(CATEGORY = "total", across(`SUM(REL_EST_AMT_SUM)`, sum)), 
    by = c("STATE_ABBR", "COUNTY_NAME", "REPORTING_YEAR", "CATEGORY")
  ) %>% 
  arrange(REPORTING_YEAR, factor(CATEGORY, unique(CATEGORY))) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(STATE_ABBR, COUNTY_NAME), 
    names_from = c(CATEGORY, REPORTING_YEAR), 
    values_from = `SUM(REL_EST_AMT_SUM)`, 
    values_fn = sum, 
    values_fill = 0L
  ) %>% 
  mutate(grand_total = rowSums(across(starts_with("total"))))
```

Output

```
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'STATE_ABBR', 'COUNTY_NAME' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 8 x 13
  STATE_ABBR COUNTY_NAME OnSite_LAND_1990 `POTW METALS_1990` AIR_1990 total_1990 OnSite_LAND_2000 `POTW METALS_2000` total_2000 OnSite_LAND_2005 AIR_2005 total_2005 grand_total
  <fct>      <fct>                  <dbl>              <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>            <dbl>              <dbl>      <dbl>            <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
1 CA         FRESNO                 23149                  0        0      23149                0                  0          0                0        0          0       23149
2 KY         TAYLOR                     0                  0        0          0                0                  0          0                0        0          0           0
3 NM         CARROLL                    0                  0      250        250                0                  0          0                0        0          0         250
4 CA         ORANGE                     0                  0        0          0               23                  0         23                0        0          0          23
5 KY         JEFFERSON                  0                  0        0          0                5                  0          5                0        0          0           5
6 NM         FRESNO                     0                  0        0          0                0               1300       1300                0        0          0        1300
7 KY         CARROLL                    0                  0        0          0                0                  0          0              123  5617000    5617123     5617123
8 KY         ORANGE                     0                  0        0          0                0                  0          0                0    14000      14000       14000
```

Some Explanations

First, see this one

```
NP %>% 
  rows_insert(
    SOME_DATA, 
    by = c("STATE_ABBR", "COUNTY_NAME", "REPORTING_YEAR", "CATEGORY")
  )
```

It inserts SOME_DATA into NP by expanding the rows. Also, it uses the combination of STATE_ABBR, COUNTY_NAME, REPORTING_YEAR and CATEGORY to identify the correct place to insert. For example, try something like this

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = letters[c(1:2, NA)], c = 0.5 + 0:2)
data
data %>% rows_insert(data.frame(a = 4, b = "z"), by = "a")
data %>% rows_insert(data.frame(a = 2, b = "x", c = 99), by = c("a", "b"))
```

You should get

```
> data <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = letters[c(1:2, NA)], c = 0.5 + 0:2)
> data
  a    b   c
1 1    a 0.5
2 2    b 1.5
3 3 <NA> 2.5
> data %>% rows_insert(data.frame(a = 4, b = "z"), by = "a")
  a    b   c
1 1    a 0.5
2 2    b 1.5
3 3 <NA> 2.5
4 4    z  NA
> data %>% rows_insert(data.frame(a = 2, b = "x", c = 99), by = c("a", "b"))
  a    b    c
1 1    a  0.5
2 2    b  1.5
3 3 <NA>  2.5
4 2    x 99.0
```

Then, the question is what is SOME_DATA? Well, it is the summary we get from this pipeline

```
(.) %>% 
  group_by(STATE_ABBR, COUNTY_NAME, REPORTING_YEAR) %>% 
  summarise(CATEGORY = "total", across(`SUM(REL_EST_AMT_SUM)`, sum))
```

In a pipeline, `.` can have multiple meanings. See below the explanations I copied from the documentation

> **Usage** lhs %>% rhs

> **Using the dot for secondary purposes**
> Often, some attribute or property of lhs is desired in the rhs call in addition to the value of lhs itself, e.g. the number of rows or columns. It is perfectly valid to use the dot placeholder several times in the rhs call, but by design the behavior is slightly different when using it inside nested function calls. In particular, if the placeholder is only used in a nested function call, lhs will also be placed as the first argument! The reason for this is that in most use-cases this produces the most readable code. For example, iris %>% subset(1:nrow(.) %% 2 == 0) is equivalent to iris %>% subset(., 1:nrow(.) %% 2 == 0) but slightly more compact. It is possible to overrule this behavior by enclosing the rhs in braces. For example, 1:10 %>% {c(min(.), max(.))} is equivalent to c(min(1:10), max(1:10))

> **Using the dot-place holder as lhs**
> When the dot is used as lhs, the result will be a functional sequence, i.e. a function which applies the entire chain of right-hand sides in turn to its input. See the examples.

So, the dot here captures `NP` from the lhs of outer pipeline. However, it may also be considered as the start of a functional sequence for the inner one. The latter usage takes higher precedence than the former one. So, we put the braces around the dot to avoid it being wrongly considered the start of a functional sequence.

```
(.) %>%
  group_by(STATE_ABBR, COUNTY_NAME, REPORTING_YEAR) %>% 
  summarise(CATEGORY = "total", across(`SUM(REL_EST_AMT_SUM)`, sum))
```

After this step

```
NP %>% 
  rows_insert(
    (.) %>% 
      group_by(STATE_ABBR, COUNTY_NAME, REPORTING_YEAR) %>% 
      summarise(CATEGORY = "total", across(`SUM(REL_EST_AMT_SUM)`, sum), .groups = "drop"), 
    by = c("STATE_ABBR", "COUNTY_NAME", "REPORTING_YEAR", "CATEGORY")
  )
```

The data becomes something that looks like this

```
       STATE_ABBR REPORTING_YEAR COUNTY_NAME    CATEGORY SUM(REL_EST_AMT_SUM) CARCINOGEN CLEAN_AIR
49717          CA           1990      FRESNO OnSite_LAND                23149          N         N
19700          CA           2000      ORANGE OnSite_LAND                   23          N         Y
67491          KY           1990      TAYLOR POTW METALS                    0          N         N
62086          KY           2000   JEFFERSON OnSite_LAND                    5          N         Y
62993          KY           2005      ORANGE         AIR                14000          Y         Y
63290          KY           2005     CARROLL         AIR              5617000          N         Y
00005          KY           2005     CARROLL OnSite_LAND                  123          N         Y
332510         NM           1990     CARROLL         AIR                  250          Y         Y
323501         NM           2000      FRESNO POTW METALS                 1300          N         Y
...10          CA           1990      FRESNO       total                23149       <NA>      <NA>
...11          CA           2000      ORANGE       total                   23       <NA>      <NA>
...12          KY           2005      ORANGE       total                14000       <NA>      <NA>
...13          KY           2005     CARROLL       total              5617123       <NA>      <NA>
...14          KY           2000   JEFFERSON       total                    5       <NA>      <NA>
...15          KY           1990      TAYLOR       total                    0       <NA>      <NA>
...16          NM           2000      FRESNO       total                 1300       <NA>      <NA>
...17          NM           1990     CARROLL       total                  250       <NA>      <NA>
```

Then we need to rearrange the data so that rows with the same REPORTING_YEAR are grouped together. We also want to keep the order of the CATEGORY column as-is. That's why we use `factor(CATEGORY, unique(CATEGORY))`. After rearranging,

```
   STATE_ABBR REPORTING_YEAR COUNTY_NAME    CATEGORY SUM(REL_EST_AMT_SUM) CARCINOGEN CLEAN_AIR
1          CA           1990      FRESNO OnSite_LAND                23149          N         N
2          KY           1990      TAYLOR POTW METALS                    0          N         N
3          NM           1990     CARROLL         AIR                  250          Y         Y
4          CA           1990      FRESNO       total                23149       <NA>      <NA>
5          KY           1990      TAYLOR       total                    0       <NA>      <NA>
6          NM           1990     CARROLL       total                  250       <NA>      <NA>
7          CA           2000      ORANGE OnSite_LAND                   23          N         Y
8          KY           2000   JEFFERSON OnSite_LAND                    5          N         Y
9          NM           2000      FRESNO POTW METALS                 1300          N         Y
10         CA           2000      ORANGE       total                   23       <NA>      <NA>
11         KY           2000   JEFFERSON       total                    5       <NA>      <NA>
12         NM           2000      FRESNO       total                 1300       <NA>      <NA>
13         KY           2005     CARROLL OnSite_LAND                  123          N         Y
14         KY           2005      ORANGE         AIR                14000          Y         Y
15         KY           2005     CARROLL         AIR              5617000          N         Y
16         KY           2005      ORANGE       total                14000       <NA>      <NA>
17         KY           2005     CARROLL       total              5617123       <NA>      <NA>
```

Then we `pivot_wider()` and get the result. That's the logic. Note that if you want to get rid of this message

> ```
> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'STATE_ABBR', 'COUNTY_NAME' (override with 
> `.groups` argument)
> ```

just do something like this

```
NP %>% 
  rows_insert(
    (.) %>% 
      group_by(STATE_ABBR, COUNTY_NAME, REPORTING_YEAR) %>% 
      summarise(CATEGORY = "total", across(`SUM(REL_EST_AMT_SUM)`, sum), .groups = "drop"), # drop the groups
    by = c("STATE_ABBR", "COUNTY_NAME", "REPORTING_YEAR", "CATEGORY")
  ) %>%
  arrange(REPORTING_YEAR, factor(CATEGORY, unique(CATEGORY)))
```

However, I can't reproduce the other error you have.

Comment: what is  %>% 
  rows_insert(
    (.) %>%  doing?

Comment: do you think you could add some comments? it looks like you repeat few of the processes which I assume is me not comprehending. and I assume to do the caricogen and clean air columns at the end I would need to do two more mutates?

Comment: i keep getting this error:::: `summarise()` regrouping output by 'STATE_ABBR' (override with `.groups` argument)
Error: `x` key values are not unique.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: wow that was really informative thank you! I really like piping but I haven't been able to play around with it especially with someone who can explain it. the online articles are helpful but seem pretty superficial.  :::::

thanks for all your work. this is a lot more code than I was expecting.  :::::

in the new code you start with, if the period is a stand in for the DF, do I need to Identify it somewhere? or should I be replacing the period with my data in this case? ::::
"make_yearly_total_cols <- 
  . %>%"

Comment: r is giving me errors for having too many arguments in select in the last couple lines?

Comment: I was able to remove the select function which I assume was to help order the columns? and I figured out that you're creating 3 individual functions that get combined at the end, so the periods that I was asking about draw their data from that final pipe set up right?

Comment: @JasonDeutsch Yes, just think of that period as `x`, make_yearly_total_cols is just a function equivalent to something like this `make_yearly_total_cols <- function(x) {x %>% ...}`

Comment: About that select part, I think there is a function from another package that is conflicted with `dplyr::select`. Anyway, that line is just for reordering, so you can safely remove it. If you want to debug for that, try changing that to `dplyr::select(...)` and see if it runs. @JasonDeutsch'